# Failed to notify project evaluation listener. To add 'ksp'. | Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to add the Room Compiler and Lifecycle Common in ksp, but the error occurred, I have the Android Studio version Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Path 4, Can anyone solve this problem?

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/plugin/mpp/pm20/KotlinCompilationData

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.adolfotech.adomusic"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.adolfotech.adomusic"
        minSdk = 23
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.palette:palette-ktx:1.0.0")
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.5")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.5")

    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2")
    ksp("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8-ktx:2.6.2")

    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.1")
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.1")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

Comment: What is your gradle and AGP(Android Gradle Plugin) versions?

Answer (score 4):

For me, using correct version for KSP solved the problem.
You can find a list of releases on the [KSP GitHub page](https://github.com/google/ksp/releases). I'm using Kotlin version `1.9.21`. So the KSP version should be `1.9.21-1.0.16`

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.21" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.21-1.0.16" apply false
}
```